# How to become customizing admin on trial version

Tags: dynamics-crm, admin, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-online, dynamics-365

I need to do some test development and created a Dynamics 365 for Sales trial account. I want to customize some fields, add some JavaScript and register Plugins.

I used a temp email address for that, because I do not want spam and the trial account can pass away in a few weeks.

When I click on Sales -> Settings, I only see three buttons, but not the ones for Customizations and Administrations.

Within the role manager, I cannot add the roles because of insufficient privileges.

I see that there is a possibility to become admin if I click on the top left and then admin, but then I have to do prove that I am the owner of the email address' domain name - and I cannot do the steps that are described here.

I am pretty sure, that it haven't been like this before. Is there any other possibility to become a customizer on the Dynamics 365 trial instance?

**Additional information: Solved**

I did a wrong turn. At the very beginning, I clicked, that I want to be a developer, but I had to click on another link like that. These links can be easily overseen.

Note to anyone out there: Go to trials.dynamic.com, chose your system and then watch out for a phrase/link like: "Are you signing up on behalf of a customer or using this trial for development purposes? Sign up here.".

However, even if you did everything the right way, you might get an instance that still does not work for development/customzing purposes. So you might have to do anything again.

Answer (score 1):

You should have done the following step, if **you** want to customize the system. Now your system is already customized by MS & **Sales** ready for you.

> On The following page, be sure to check **None of these. Don't customize my trial**, then click **Complete Setup.**

[image]

[Reference](https://support.clickdimensions.com/hc/en-us/articles/115001168154-Sign-up-for-a-Dynamics-365-trial?mobile_site=true)

Comment: You can refer https://community.dynamics.com/crm/f/117/t/221117  for few troubleshooting steps like Promote to admin, create new user, etc.